# Why would you ever want to create a method called *foo() instead of just foo()?

Tags: c++, programming-languages, methods

I see this in other people's code sometimes:

```
public void *foo() {
...
}

public void bar() {
...
}
```

but I never understood what the meaning of the `*` was for, and if there is any difference between `public void *foo()` and `public void foo()`?

***This is C++ code here!

Comment: What language are you talking about?

Comment: Off-topic here.  May be ok for stack overflow.  In the meantime, go read the fine manual.

Comment: Pretty sure the same answer (RTFineM) will be given on SO as well.

Comment: should it not be like "public: void *for() {}"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`public void *foo()` is a public function that returns a void pointer (which can be anything essentially). More documentation on pointers can be found here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/ (specifically the void pointer section).

`public void *foo()` and `public void* foo()` are the same and the position of `*` is purely a style thing (although the style can have implications when used elsewhere).

`public void foo()` is a public function that returns nothing.

Comment: Is `public` allowed to be used like that in C++?  I don't recall ever seeing it, but I've been programming heavily in 3 different languages recently and they're all getting muddled.

Comment: You're right: It should be `public:` with the signatures following. Was just using the OP's examples :)

Comment: Some elaboration about the style thing: Syntactically, the * binds to the variable name, not the type, so `int* foo, bar` declares one int-pointer variable (foo) and one plain int (bar), which is not what the syntax suggests. `int *foo, bar` makes it a bit more obvious.

Comment: tdammers, wouldn't it be more correct (and clear) to say "int **foo, *bar" instead of just "int *foo, bar"?

Also, that's really strange that "int* foo, bar" doesn't apply int* to both foo and bar! Usually if you do something like "float foo, bar", it creates TWO floats right? Then "int* foo, bar" logically should create TWO int*

Comment: Sorry for all the italicizing... I think stackoverflow is formatting things strangely after I included all the *'s

Answer (score 2):

The spacing is confusing you. `void *foo(int)` is the same thing as `void* foo(int)`. The former returns `void *`, the latter does not return anything. Some people prefer to attach the '*' to the type precisely to avoid this confusion.